# Using Python to download website

Tags: python

Trying to download the website with python, but getting errors. My intention is to download the website, extract relevant information from it using python, save result to another file on my hard disk. Having trouble on step 1. Other steps were working until some strange SSL error. I am using python 2.7

```
import urllib
testsite = urllib.URLopener()
testsite.retrieve("https://thepiratebay.se/top/207", "C:\file.html")
```

This is what happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Xaero\Desktop\Python\class related\scratch.py", line 10, in <module>
    testsite.retrieve("https://thepiratebay.se/top/207", "C:\file.html")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 237, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 435, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 940, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 803, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 755, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1156, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 342, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 281, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

Did some research online, and it turns out Piratebay is very python-unfriendly. I found some code that gives it a different user agent, and makes it load the page, but this too stopped working very recently. >_<

Generates the same error:

```
import urllib2
import os
import datetime
import time
from urllib import FancyURLopener
from random import choice

today = datetime.datetime.today()
today = today.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
    'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.0.12) Gecko/20070731 Ubuntu/dapper-security Firefox/1.5.0.12']


class MyOpener(FancyURLopener, object):
    version = choice(user_agents)

myopener = MyOpener()
page = myopener.retrieve('https://thepiratebay.se/top/207', 'C:\TPB.HDMovies' + today + '.html')
```

Is anyone out there able to do this successfully?

Comment: Try using the `requests` package (installable via pip) instead of `urllib` (and generally you should use the built-in `urllib2` package over `urllib` anyway. It looks like the error relates to the server only wanting to allow TLSv2 but your client only using v1. IIRC there is some issue in some [older] versions of python with the urllib package not using newer versions of TLS. Upgrading to the latest version of python 2 or 3 might also help.

Comment: What exact version of Python are you using?  Some websites require SNI, which is a newish SSL feature.  Python 2.7.0 didn't support that; I know that some bits of the latest Python 2.7.x have added support for SNI, but I don't know if the "urllib" module supports SNI.  You could try the latest Python 2.7 with the "requests" library, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: I suspect they (and many other legitimate websites which depend on people visiting them and so don't want their data to be scraped) are not so much python-unfriendly as scraping-unfriendly. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using selenium?

```
pip install selenium
```

See [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/installation.html) for further installation instructions.

First import selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Then begin the webdriver and load the page:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://thepiratebay.se/top/207")
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating python install fixed it. I guess I had 2.7.0, updated to 2.7.11 and issue went away.

Retrieves the page flawlessly now:

```
import urllib2
import os
import datetime
import time
from urllib import FancyURLopener
from random import choice

today = datetime.datetime.today()
today = today.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
    'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.0.12) Gecko/20070731 Ubuntu/dapper-security Firefox/1.5.0.12']


class MyOpener(FancyURLopener, object):
    version = choice(user_agents)

myopener = MyOpener()
page = myopener.retrieve('https://thepiratebay.se/top/207', 'C:\TPB.HDMovies' + today + '.html')
```

Although, that selenium looks interesting too. I will check it out. Thank you for all your help guys! =D